# "The last time" vs. "one last time"

Tags: difference, phrases

Could you tell me if there is any difference in meaning and usage between *the last time* and *one last time*? For example:

> Dad, can I use your car **the last time**?
>
> Dad, can I use your car **one last time**?

By the way, do I need to include *for* before the phrases or is it totally optional? For example:

> Dad, can I use your car **for** the last time?
>
> Dad, can I use your car **for** one last time?

Comment: Dad might say *This is the last time* as he hands you the keys, but it's not very idiomatic for you to use the definite article form when ***asking***. Note that ***one*** is effectively an "intensified, emphatic" alternative to the (definite *or* indefinite) article in such contexts. For some reason that's not clear to me, if you ***are*** going to use the definite article, it's MUCH MORE idiomatic if you also include ***for***, whereas if you use ***one*** instead of ***the***, including ***for*** as well is entirely arbitrary (your versions #2 and #4 are both absolutely fine).

Comment: Thank you for trying to explain it, but could you please tell me why it's not okey to say "Dad, can I use your car for the last time?"?

Comment: I only said it's "not very idiomatic". That doesn't necessarily mean it's "not okay" - it's just ***not very likely***. And I'd say that because in practice you'd almost always be *emphasizing* the fact of it being the last time you intend to borrow the car (Yeah, yeah! :), then if you were a native speaker you'd almost certainly convey that emphasis by using ***one***, not ***the***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need "for" in the first example to make it idiomatic:

- Dad, can I use your car **for** the last time?
- Dad, can I use your car one last time?

"The last time" can refer to a *previous* time, so without "for" to indicate a future possibility it doesn't fit with the tense of the question. There is another issue with this first example though - in at least some British dialects, adding "for the last time" to the end of a question can mean "*this is the last time I am going to ask*" and express annoyance.

That aside, the difference between the two questions as they are intended is that the definite article "the" makes it seem more final - "*the last*" is definitely the last.

"One last time" infers *an additional use*, and that perhaps the previous occasion was believed to be "the last".